# Inorder Binary Tree Traversal

Tags: python, list, traversal, inorder

I created Binary Tree with some nodes and trying to get the result of inorder traversal using dictionary, but It does not really work.
Why the list does not append, even tho it prints the result?

```
class TreeNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
         self.val = val
         self.left = left
         self.right = right

def inoder(bomj):
    visited = []

    if bomj:
        inoder(bomj.left)
        print(bomj.val)
        visited.append(bomj.val)
        inoder(bomj.right)

    return visited

tree = TreeNode(1)
tree.left = TreeNode(2)
tree.right = TreeNode(3)
tree.left.left = TreeNode(4)
tree.left.right = TreeNode(5)
tree.left.left.left = TreeNode(7)
tree.right.left = TreeNode(6)
print(inoder(tree))
```

```
Result:
7
4
2
5
1
6
3
[1]
```

I also tried using dictionary

Comment: Try saving the results of the recursion - e.g. `inoder(bomj.left)` -> `visited.extend(inoder(bomj.left))`.

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting `internal` every time you call `inorder`.  You need a variable `inorder` that's outside the recursion.

```
def inorder(bomj):
    visited = []

    def internal(bomj):
        if bomj:
            internal(bomj.left)
            print(bomj.val)
            visited.append(bomj.val)
            internal(bomj.right)

    internal(bomj)
    return visited
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the code too much, you can just merge the list:

```
def inoder(bomj):
    visited = []

    if bomj:
        left = inoder(bomj.left)
        print(bomj.val)
        right = inoder(bomj.right)
        visited = left + [bomj.val] + right

    return visited
```

Comment: Beware: This has quadratic runtime in the worst case since list concatenation is linear time and the tree need not be balanced. In the best case, if the tree is balanced, this will have linearithmic runtime, when it could have linear runtime.

Comment: Yes, ideally it's better to just use global list or pass the main list as recursive function parameter, I was just intending to show that the in order representation is prepended and appended that way

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data structure to collect the values by reference as a parameter argument.

Updated code:

```
class TreeNode:
 def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
     self.val = val
     self.left = left
     self.right = right

def inorder(bomj):
    visited = []
    _inorder(bomj, visited)
    return visited

def _inorder(bomj, nodes):
    if bomj:
        _inorder(bomj.left, nodes)
        nodes.append(bomj.val)
        _inorder(bomj.right, nodes)

tree = TreeNode(1)
tree.left = TreeNode(2)
tree.right = TreeNode(3)
tree.left.left = TreeNode(4)
tree.left.right = TreeNode(5)
tree.left.left.left = TreeNode(7)
tree.right.left = TreeNode(6)
print(inorder(tree))
```

Result:

```
[7, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 3]
```